# How to set keyboard layout for a macbook Pro?

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout

I'm running Ubuntu in VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro.

I chose a 'French (Mac)' layout (see below).
[image]

Unfortunately, the character | (vertical bar) does not seem to be mapped!
Usually, in Mac OSX, I get it by pressing: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

How can I add a vertical bar (any key combination would be ok) to this keyboard?

Comment: This Mac keyboard layout has 3 major flaws: [return]
• doesn't permit to type correct French, ex. missing: É, È, Ù… [return]
• doesn't permit to type Unix commands, missing: \, | [return]
• many of the key mapping are too cumbersome to be memorized.

Comment: @danielAzuelos É is not missing : first, press down the Caps Lock key and then press any other letter key to have it capitalized (including accentuated ones). For \ and | just press Alt+Shift+/ and Alt+Shift+L respectively.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my "commandline solution" (Ubuntu 12.04 server on MacBookPro 10.9 within VirtualBox 4.3.8) :

```
sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Keyboard-configuration choices for MackBookPro French keyboard:

> -> MacBook / MacBookPro (Intl)
>
> -> French
>
> -> French (again)
>
> -> Right Alt (AltGr)
>
> -> No Compose Key

It seems keyboard settings works fine and are keep after reboot.

--- EDIT Thomas ---

You should install all the console tools to make it work

```
apt-get install console-data

apt-get install console-setup

apt-get install console-locales

apt-get install keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly on VirtualBox, but with a fresh install on VMWare it did not match perfectly my layout: the "-" key for example types "§"

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution for VMWare, since this topic comes first when searching for it on Google:

As Pascal said, launch the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and select the following option in the opened interface:

> -> MacBook / MacBookPro (Intl)
>
> -> French
>
> -> French (again)
>
> -> Right Alt (AltGr)
>
> -> No Compose Key

Once it is done, go in your VMWare **preferences**, then **Mouse and Keyboard**, and disable **Keyboard mapping for languages**. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution for French Canadian MacBooks, since French Canadian MacBooks are different from French ones, and the configuration is tricky to find.

> sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Then

> -> MacBook / MacBookPro (Intl)
>
> -> French (Canada)
>
> -> Canadian Multilingual (do not choose French Canada again)
>
> -> Right Alt (AltGr)
> -> No Compose Key

Answer (score 0):

What did the tick for me (I have to say I'm not an expert by far) with 20.04 (not 18.04) on VMWare Fusion 11.5.7 :

1. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`

2. reboot
3. Fusion preferences > keyboard & mouse > disable mapping for langages
4. use the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, not the left   <kbd>Alt</kbd> key